# How to pad the location for the image on the label?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

**How to pad the location for the image on the label?**

---

I am working on project in which the image is basically the size of the label and some text that I want to show isn't visible...when I remove the image, the label text is shown. I have to pad the location for the image on the label.

Comment: Please explain your question further...

Comment: You might need to look at `ipadx` or `compound`

Comment: I am working on project in which the image is basically the size of the label and some text that I want to show isn't visible...when I remove the image, the label text is shown. I have to pad the location for the image on the label. @SaeedEmamYari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label automatically resizes to account for the size of the image, so what you can do is, use the `compound` option to move the image to whichever position you prefer.

From a doc:

> If you would like the `Label` widget to display both text and a graphic (either a bitmap or an image), the compound option specifies the relative orientation of the graphic relative to the text. Values may be any of `tk.LEFT`, `tk.RIGHT`, `tk.CENTER`, `tk.BOTTOM`, or `tk.TOP`. For example, if you specify `compound=BOTTOM`, the graphic will be displayed below the text.

So:

```
Label(root,text='Image 1',image=img,compound='top').pack()
```